# Swift/XCode 14.0.1 - Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, fatal-error

I am trying to work on a project for my OOP class that was designed to work in xCode version 11.6, and I am receiving an error in the Thinking Cell group, which is not part of the assignment (possibly due to the fact I am running the latest xCode 14.0.1 instead of 11.6).
The project is ChatBot (chapter 17) from the "Intro to App Development with Swift" lessons.

---

```
import UIKit

// Used to indicate that the bot is "thinking". It contains a single image view which can be animated.


class ThinkingCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var thinkingImage: UIImageView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        thinkingImage.animationImages = (1...3).map {
            index in
            return UIImage(named: "thinking\(index)")!
        }
        thinkingImage.animationDuration = 1
    }
}
```

---

Error on this line:
return UIImage(named: "thinking(index)")!

Error received:
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

---

My guess is that there is an issue with the index, which shows as value 1, show in the screenshot: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnFUu.png)
This is my first post on stack overflow, so let me know if there is any issues.
Thanks again!

Comment: That would mean that the image you are asking for is not part of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue was in how the project was downloaded from the index site where the project files were hosted.
The thinking(index) was referring to thinking1, which was a file that included in the assets folder, but the actual pictures were blank because they were replaced with index.html files.
After redownloading the files, I was able to get the pictures that were associated with thinking, and then the error went away.